# Inserting read and write barriers at field accesses using SOOT in Java code

Tags: java, field, memory-barriers, soot

Sorry if it's a basic question but even after searching a lot, I'm not able to figure this out.

I'm using SOOT to instrument my code. I'm able to check whether my statement accesses a field using `stmt.containsFieldRef()` but I want to differentiate between a statement writing a value to the field and another which is just reading its value.

Is there a pre-defined method to do that or is parsing the statement the only option?

Answer (score 1):

I also met this question and I finally figure it out by myself.

```java
try{
    if (stmt.getDefBoxes().get(0).getValue().getClass() == Class.forName("soot.jimple.StaticFieldRef") ||
        stmt.getDefBoxes().get(0).getValue().getClass() == Class.forName("soot.jimple.internal.JInstanceFieldRef")){
        isWrite = true;
    }else{
        isWrite = false;
    }
}catch (Exception e){}
```

This can work because I found that `stmt.getDefBoxes()` return a list related to the left-hand-side variable. If left-hand-side variable is of type `soot.jimple.internal.JimpleLocal`, it is a read action; If it is of type class `soot.jimple.internal.JInstanceFieldRef` or class `soot.jimple.StaticFieldRef`, it is a write action.